# How to crawl a feed

Tags: rss, web-crawler, feed, atom-feed

My application needs to keep track of RSS/Atom feeds and save the new entries in a database. My question is, **What is the most reliable method to determine whether an entry in a feed has already been crawled or not?**

I use [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/) module to parse the feeds. My current implementation keeps record of the latest value of `feed.entry[i].updated_parsed`, when crawling if `updated_parsed` value of an entry is greater than the recorded value, then that entry is saved in the database. The problem here is that many feeds don't have a published date or an updated date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be determining whether you've already crawled an entry by reference to its `<guid>` primarily (falling back to `<link>` in the absence of a `<guid>`), and anything to do with dates only as a secondary analysis.